# ".addView()" for simple views

Tags: android, android-layout

As you can see in the image, I can select the view and 3 ImageViews get added using "_root.addView(dragIcon);".

My problem is that the view is a simple view and not a ViewGroup , which means that in this picture i had to add the 3 images to the RelativeView Background "root.addView(dragIcon);" Instead of to the Green rectangle view shown in the image.

I'm pretty sure i can't change the View to a ViewGroup becuase a lot of methods (ex. onTouch) require a "View". I've tried casting the View to a ViewGroup "((ViewGroup) view).addView(dragIcon);" but that did't work.

You can make multiple Views in the app and drag them around, so I need to make the 3 images children to the specific parent View.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

[image: The Image]

Here is the part of the code that's relevant to this question...

```
_root = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.root); //This is the background
_view = new View(this); //This is the View (Green in the Image)

private void selectView(final View view) {
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    ImageView dragIcon, sizeIconTop, sizeIconBottom;

                    if (view.getTag(R.string.viewSelected) != "1") {
                        view.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00AA00);
                        view.setTag(R.string.viewSelected, "1");

                        double Ypos = view.getTranslationY() - view.getHeight() / 2;

                        // Set draggable (6*3 grid on the right)
                        dragIcon = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                        dragIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.drabicon);
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imgParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        imgParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                        imgParams.setMargins(0,0,30,0);
                        dragIcon.setLayoutParams(imgParams);
                        dragIcon.setTranslationY((float) Ypos + 70 + view.getHeight() / 2);
                        _root.addView(dragIcon); //Need to change from _root.addView to view.addView

                        // Set size top (White line at the top)
                        sizeIconTop = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                        sizeIconTop.setImageResource(R.drawable.resize);
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams stImgParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        stImgParams.setMargins(0,0,30,0);
                        stImgParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                        sizeIconTop.setLayoutParams(stImgParams);
                        sizeIconTop.setTranslationY((float) Ypos + 99);
                        _root.addView(sizeIconTop); //Need to change from _root.addView to view.addView

                        // Set size bottom (White line at the bottom)
                        sizeIconBottom = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                        sizeIconBottom.setImageResource(R.drawable.resize);
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams sbImgParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        sbImgParams.setMargins(0,0,30,0);
                        sbImgParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                        sizeIconBottom.setLayoutParams(sbImgParams);
                        sizeIconBottom.setTranslationY((float) Ypos + 93 + view.getHeight());
                        _root.addView(sizeIconBottom); //Need to change from _root.addView to view.addView


                    } else { //Ignore this part

                        //((ViewGroup) view).removeView(dragIcon);
                        //((ViewGroup) view).removeView(sizeIconTop);
                        //((ViewGroup) view).removeView(sizeIconBottom);

                        view.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
                        view.setTag(R.string.viewSelected, "0");
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though the question is a bit confusing, after analysing your code I figured out what you wanted to do.
Unfortunately, you have to choose whether to use a **View** (and not being able to attach the ImageViews) or using a **ViewGroup** (and handling the events yourself).

Since your View is a View, and your 3 ImageViews are also Views (means they are at the same level of usage), you can not add the last 3 to the first.

**The rule is :** *You can add ViewGroups and Views to a ViewGroup, but you can not add Views or ViewGroups to a View. Views are supposed to be the elementary block of Android design.*

> `void addView (View child)`
>
> *Adds a child view. If no layout parameters
>   are already set on the child, the default parameters for this
>   ViewGroup are set on the child.*

In my opinion, I would make View a ViewGroup and take care of the **TouchEvents** by myself.

[Check this documentation/code regarding  TouchEvents on ViewGroups](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html)

Let me know of your progress. Will be glad to help you.

Regards,

Comment: I know it was confusing, but thank you for the reply, I'll try it out.

Comment: Hi @Axonshi123 . Any news on the matter? Was it helpful?